# $f(x) = x^{2}\sin(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x= 0$. Which proof is wrong regarding continuity

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Let $f(x) = x^{2}\sin(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x= 0$.

Let $x_{n} = 1/n\pi$. Note that $x_{n} \to 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_{n}) =0$. But if $y_{n} = 2/n\pi \to 0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(y_{n}) = \infty$. So the function is not continuous at $x=0$

Now notice another test: How $-1\leq \sin(1/x) \leq 1$ then $-|x|^{2} \leq f(x) \leq |x|^{2}$. Then, by the confrontation theorem, we have that the function is continuous at $0$.

Which proof is wrong? Why?

Comment: Why do you think that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) = \infty$?

Comment: I think you have accidentally considered $x^2/\sin(1/x)$ instead of $x^2 \sin(1/x)$ when doing your limit for $y_n$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(y_n)$ does not tend to $\infty$.  $\sin (\frac 1 {y_n}) $ is bounded and $y_n^{2} \to 0$ so $f(y_n) \to 0$.

Comment: True, so the second proof is correct.